# Dispose and restart OpenGLView in monodroid

Tags: xamarin.android, xamarin

I'm trying to dispose and restart an OpenGLView or AndroidGameView within the same Activity, but it seems the game can't start another time after disposed inside the same Activity. Here is my test using monodroid game sample project:

```
GLView1 view;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create our OpenGL view, and display it
        //view = new GLView1(this);
        //SetContentView(view);

        Timer timer = new Timer(OnTimerDone, this, 3000, 3000);
    }

    void OnTimerDone(object state)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timer");
        ((Activity)state).RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                if (view != null)
                {
                    //view.Stop();
                    view.Dispose();
                    view = null;
                    SetContentView(null);
                    GC.Collect();
                }
                else
                {
                    view = new GLView1((Activity)state);
                    //view.Resume();
                    SetContentView(view);
                }
            });
    }

    //protected override void OnPause()
    //{
    //    base.OnPause();
    //    view.Pause();
    //}

    //protected override void OnResume()
    //{
    //    base.OnResume();
    //    view.Resume();
    //}
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Update with my new code to avoid reuse SetContentView:

```
GLView1 view;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        // Create our OpenGL view, and display it
        //view = new GLView1(this);
        //SetContentView(view);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Timer timer = new Timer(OnTimerDone, this, 3000, 3000);
    }

    void OnTimerDone(object state)
    {
        ((Activity)state).RunOnUiThread(() =>
            {
                LinearLayout linearLayoutMain = ((Activity)state).FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutMain);
                if (view != null)
                {
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timer delete");
                    linearLayoutMain.RemoveView(view);
                    try
                    {
                        view.Stop();
                        view.Dispose();
                        view = null;
                        //SetContentView(null);
                        GC.Collect();
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        //Android.Util.Log.Debug("ex:", ex.ToString());
                        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("ex:" + ex);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    view = new GLView1((Activity)state);
                    view.Run();
                    //view.Resume();
                    //SetContentView(view);
                    linearLayoutMain.AddView(view);
                    System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("timer create");

                }
            });
    }
```

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: I don't get any error: the GLView isn't disposed correctly I think because the timer is stopped the second time without throwing any exception! I also try to not reuse SetContentView, but the problem remains the same.

Comment: This might be a silly question but have you tried wrapping it in a Try/Catch block and outputting any Exception messages? I find that I have to do that sometimes with MonoTouch as some exceptions are swallowed by the runtime.

Comment: Yes, I know this bug especially when using threads, but I tried without getting any result. The timer is stopped and that's all!

Comment: What if you move the SetContentView(null) above view.Dispose() ??

Comment: SetContentView is removed now as I tell in a previous comment. I updated my question with the new code.

Comment: Why don't you wrap the whole block in try/catch?

Comment: I try and same problem: no exception thrown. Seems definitely to be a bad dispose corrected by android activity closing which cleans it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a play around with your code and found that the `Timer` *was* still running but the block inside `RunOnUiThread()` wasn't being called. I removed the `view.Stop()` method and the `view.Dispose()` and it started working correctly.

Here is my full code (using a 5000ms interval for the time)

```
    GLView1 view;

    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);

        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        Timer timer = new Timer(OnTimerDone, this, 5000, 5000);
    }

    void OnTimerDone(object state)
    {
        RunOnUiThread(() =>
        {
            try
            {
                LinearLayout linearLayoutMain = ((Activity)state).FindViewById<LinearLayout>(Resource.Id.linearLayoutMain);

                if (view != null)
                {
                    linearLayoutMain.RemoveView(view);
                    view = null;
                }
                else
                {
                    view = new GLView1(this);
                    view.Run();
                    linearLayoutMain.AddView(view);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            }
        });
    }
```

The old View appears to still be garbage-collected (see in the log below). I don't think the extra calls were necessary. I ran the application for about 15 minutes straight with no issues.

```
11-16 00:30:05.828 D/dalvikvm( 2144): GC_EXPLICIT freed 119K, 6% free 8813K/9351K, paused 3ms+5ms, total 56ms
11-16 00:30:08.047 D/dalvikvm( 2144): GC_CONCURRENT freed 992K, 12% free 8270K/9351K, paused 4ms+36ms, total 162ms
11-16 00:30:10.667 D/dalvikvm( 2144): GC_CONCURRENT freed 202K, 10% free 8467K/9351K, paused 5ms+63ms, total 116ms
```

Comment: Thank you. I will never try to do the GC job anymore !